# Allow Quick Create Form for Connections in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there a work around in Dynamics CRM 2013 to turn on quick create in the Connection entity? The "Allow quick create" is gray so it cannot be selected. I can only find reference to activities being unable to utilize quick create. There is no mention of connections. Does anyone have a work around?

Answer (score 1):

i think it's not possible because by default in ms crm 2013  following entities are enabled for the Global Quick Create: Contacts,Cases, Activities (Tasks, Phones Calls, E-mails and Appointments), Accounts,  Competitors,, Leads and Opportunities........

Comment: Additional detail: You can only enable Quick Create for the "updated" entities - the ones that have a 2013 style form with Command bar and not old CRM 4.0 (toolbar) or 2011 (Ribbon) forms

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible because it's a special kind of entity provided by MS Dynamics out of the box. As you can see, Account does allow you to choose the "Quick Create" option, whereas another entity "Connection Role" does not.

Also, when adding a connection, you always start from the entity that you want to add a connection to. As such, it wouldn't make much sense to have it as a Quick Create, because there is, I believe, no "blank" form when creating a Connection. Before you create a connection, the form is always aware of your source entity, the entity you want to add the connection to.

Comment: This is not relevant - you can use Quick Create for child records (eg a Contact from an Account) and it will map fields as usual, including the lookup to the parent, which is what you are doing when you create a Connection.

Comment: I don't believe he's asking for a quick create for child records but for connection entity itself.

Comment: That's right. And Connections are simply a built-in entity that has two parents via two lookups. However, my point is that it has nothing to do with it being "special". Connections are not an updated entity, and I think it is this that prevents them being enabled.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying now, only updated CRM 2013 entities were given this ability? You should post it as answer.